# css make options select appear next to each other in rows

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have made a colorpicker on the shop pages of a woocommerce store.
On the backend, a client can make variations and set the colors for each variation.
On the frontside the customer can choose this color and then add it to the basket.

What is working now, is with display:inline-block to make the options appear next to eachother.
However, when a product has many color variations, the options are to wide for the column.
So i want the options to fit into the column width and start on the next row if full.
However, this doesnt seem to work. I tried display grid and display flex on the parent item (select), use float:left and so on but no succes so far.

I want 4 items next to eachother, then another row of four items.

HTML:

```
    <select size="8" id="kleuren">
<option class="colorpicker-pick" style="border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: url(); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left center;"></option>
<option value="956" style="background-color: rgb(26, 178, 216)"></option>
<option value="960" style="background-color: rgb(221, 11, 11)"></option>
<option value="961" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)"></option>
<option value="962" style="background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211)"></option>
<option value="963" style="background-color: rgb(129, 215, 66)"></option>
<option value="964" style="background-color: rgb(221, 145, 31)"></option>
<option value="965" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)"></option>
<option value="966" style="background-color: rgb(237, 237, 7)"></option>
    </select>
```

Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify select in this way unfortunately.

You can just do it another way using checkboxes, something like this:

> CSS

```
.grid-container{
    display:grid !important;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
<label for="color1">
    Option 1
    <input type="checkbox" id="option-1" name="inputName[]">
</label>
<label for="color2">
    Option 2
    <input type="checkbox" id="option-2" name="inputName[]">
</label>
<label for="color3">
    Option 3
    <input type="checkbox" id="option-3" name="inputName[]">
</label>
<label for="color4">
    Option 4
    <input type="checkbox" id="option-4" name="inputName[]">
</label>
```

Comment: I was afraid of this... ok that means i have some more work to do...

Answer (score 0):

It totally is doable! took me a while to figure out tho lol.

Make your option `display:inline`, and on your select add a `size="2"` tag.

`select=2` will lay out all the options in rows under each other, then the inline on options will make them align in a row. I recommend wrapping the select then in a div and setting a fixed height with overflow-clip, so the empty row that is the result of the select hack gets hidden.

Check this tailwind playground for example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/boZINi1uRs